# segmentation fault (core dumped) using structures and pointers

Tags: c++, postgresql, pointers, struct

this is the first time I am asking a question here, so here is the context:

The project on which I work to is confidential and quite complex, however, it is a mix of C C++ and PostgreSQL, it is all I can say. Neverthless, here is a minimum WORKING example (that actually compile fine) but throws an error after generation of object code:

`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
typedef size_t Size;
#define INDEX_SIZE_MASK   0x1FFF
typedef struct IndexTupleData
{
    //ItemPointerData t_tid;        /* reference TID to heap tuple */

    /* ---------------
     * t_info is laid out in the following fashion:
     *
     * 15th (high) bit: has nulls
     * 14th bit: has var-width attributes
     * 13th bit: AM-defined meaning
     * 12-0 bit: size of tuple
     * ---------------
     */

    unsigned int t_info;        /* various info about tuple */

} IndexTupleData;               /* MORE DATA FOLLOWS AT END OF STRUCT */
typedef IndexTupleData *IndexTuple;
#define IndexTupleDSize(itup)       ((Size) ((itup).t_info & INDEX_SIZE_MASK))
int main ()

{
IndexTuple itup;
(*itup).t_info = 1;
cout << ((*itup).t_info) << endl;


//cout << *itup.t_info << endl;
//int itemsz = IndexTupleDSize(*itup);


//cout << itup.t_info << endl;

//cout << *itup.t_info << endl;


return 0;
}
```

`

While the compilation / linking is quite simple:

g++ -c IndexTupleDSize.cpp

g++ -o I IndexTupleDSize.o

./I

Then, it throws:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I know that according to [Pointers in C with Segmentation fault (core dumped) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601234/pointers-in-c-with-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-error?newreg=8ad37ce1c38445deb65b726de7624677) and many related subjects found at Google; the problem is the fact that I want to access a memory zone that I am not allowed to. Another hint, is using the arrow operator ( itup->t_info instead of *itup.t_info ), the two block codes compile but the final result is the same...

Can you please explain why and how it throws this error?

Comment: `(*itup).t_info = 1;`, nopes. You only have a pointer that does not point to any valid memory.

Comment: `itup` is a pointer, which means it's a variable that stores the address of another variable. Where is the other variable whose address you want it to store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must allocate objects to be accessed and assign their pointers before dereferencing pointers.

```
int main ()

{
    IndexTuple itup;
    itup = new IndexTupleData; // allocate object and assign its pointer
    
    (*itup).t_info = 1;
    cout << ((*itup).t_info) << endl;



    delete itup; // delete allocated object

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works fine, thanks.

The issue was that I haven't analyzed much the previous code blocks in the real project, so when I had to reproduce it, I have totally forgot to think about it (declaring the pointer AND freeing it of course).

Thank you all again! 

The subject can be closed. :)